# Restore Windows system image on larger partition (Bootcamp)

Tags: windows-7, windows, partitioning, boot-camp, system-restore

I'm using **Bootcamp** to sideload Windows (7 Pro) on MacBook Pro. Current windows partition has not enough free space. I've created a `Windows system image` using **Backup and Restore**. I wonder if can I delete current partition and create a new partition and restore the `system image` on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me what utility you've used for the backup, and therefore how you'd do the restore. In principle, though, this approach will work. The big (and I mean ***BIG***) caveat is this:

***NEVER USE WINDOWS PARTITIONING TOOLS ON A [HYBRID MBR](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) DISK!!!!***

Apple's Boot Camp reconfigures the disk as a hybrid MBR, in which the normal Mac [GUID Partition Table's (GPT's)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) protective MBR is modified to hold duplicate information on up to three GPT partitions. OS X uses the GPT partitions directly, whereas Windows reads the MBR partitions and ignores the GPT data. Thus, if you use a Windows partitioning tool, you'll modify the MBR data but not the GPT data. This mis-matched GPT and MBR partition data will almost certainly result in serious damage to one or more partitions. (Some third-party Windows tools know enough to avoid this disastrous consequence, but the standard tools delivered with Windows *will* trash a hybrid MBR disk.)

Instead, you should delete, resize, and create new partitions using GPT-aware tools such as Apple's Disk Utility or the GParted tool in Linux. (In fact, GParted may be able to resize your existing partitions, which may be easier than a backup-and-restore operation -- but resizing is risky enough that backing up any partition you resize is advisable.) After making these changes, you may need to re-create your hybrid MBR using a tool such as `gptsync` (which comes with [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/)) or [GPT fdisk (`gdisk`).](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/)